# How to iterate every 10 lines on CSV file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

```
with open(example.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in readCSV:
        Do something.
```

I need to skip every 10 lines in for loop, but doing readCSV[::10] won't work.

Comment: Increment row count in loop, if rowNum % 10 == 0.. Skip

Answer (score 2):

This boils down to iterating over every 10<sup>th</sup> element from a generator, which can be done with `itertools.islice`:

```
import itertools
import csv

with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in itertools.islice(readCSV, None, None, 10):
        # Do something.
```

This does the equivalent of slicing a list (as in `list[::10]`) on a generator.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for i, row in enumerate(readCSV):
        if i % 10 == 0:
            # do stuff with every 10th row
```

Comment: Using `enumerate` is clearer and less error-prone than manually keeping  a counter.

Comment: Not familiar with `enumerate` but do you need a second for loop? Can you just have the first for loop say `for i, row in enumerate(readCSV):`

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the index with an iterator

```
with open(example.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    i = 0
    for row in readCSV:
        if i%10 = 0:
            continue
        Do something.
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to

```
count = 0
for line in f:
    count+=1
    if count % 10 == 0: 
        print line
```